# Insertion Sort Printing Wrong Output

Tags: c++, arrays, sorting, insertion-sort

I am trying to sort an array using the code below:-

The expected output should be an array which is sorted in ascending order.

But when i tried to run this code the output comes out to be 59 (6 times)

I have tried debugging it added a watch at first array declaration and added a breakpoint on the first for loop it gives out the error to be :-

```
->->error-begin 
A syntax error in expression, near `A[6]={31,41,59,26,41,58}'.
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    int A[6]={31,41,59,26,41,58};;
int j;
int length = 6;
    for(j=2;j<length;j++)
    {
        int key;
        key = A[j];
        int i;
        i=j-1;
        while(i>0 && A[i]>key)
        {
            A[i+1]=A[i];
            i=i-1;
        }
    A[i+1]=key;
cout<<A[j];

    }


return 0;
}
```

Update:

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    int A[6] = { 31, 41, 59, 26, 41, 58 };
    int temp;
    int j;
    int length = 6;
    for (j = 2; j < length; j++) {
        int key;
        key = A[j];
        int i;
        i = j - 1;
        while (i > 0 && A[i] > key) {
            temp = A[i + 1];
            A[i + 1] = A[i];
            A[i] = temp;
            i = i - 1;
        }
        A[i + 1] = key;
    }
    cout << A[j];

    return 0;
}
```

It's working is supposed to be like a bubble sort I do know about

```
std::sort(std::begin(A), std::end(A));
```

But I am curious why this code isn't working, I have already tried looking up wiki and other sites for similar code but i can't seem to find anything relevant.

Comment: What happens to value at `A[i+1]` when you execute `A[i+1]=A[i];`?

Comment: ***But I am curious why this code isn't working*** Why don't you use your debugger. I mean step through the code line by line looking at your variables.

Comment: @Pontifex it's supposed to swap the values I have taken the pseudo code from Introduction to Algorithms CLRS

Comment: ***it's supposed to swap the values*** It certainly does not do that.

Comment: @Saubhagya Srivastava I know what it's supposed to do. What it does is making two copies of `A[i]` and none of `A[i+1]`.

Comment: @drescherjm I have already tried that only error I can come up with is mention about I can't see any foreign characters (unrecognised by Dev c++ complier).

Comment: You probably did not look carefully enough to notice the bug with the code that was supposed to swap. I mean after this line `A[i+1]=A[i];` you would have had to inspect A[i+1] and A[i] in your debugger.

Comment: @Pontifex  I have already tried to make a temp variable and swap the values but the error is still not resolved ..

Comment: ***I have already tried to make a temp variable and swap the values but the error is still not resolved*** show your implementation of swap. Should be very easy to debug it now that you know what it is supposed to do and what to look for.

Comment: `temp = A[i+1];
   A[i+1]=A[i];
   A[i]=temp;`@drescherjm

Comment: @Pontifex is that right?

Comment: Alright, I checked it. The array actually is sorted, output is correct **if you print it outside the loop.** You were trying to look into it before sorting had been finished.

Comment: @Pontifex warning: array subscript is above array bounds [-Warray-bounds] if i print it  out of the for loop, what compiler are you using can you attach the code and link?

Comment: ... and how exactly are you doing that?

Comment: @Pontifex [1] (http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/d5e0e370095149f2) even without the temp part it's showing up same error

Comment: You are reusing variable `j`, which now contains value `6`; even if it was a valid index, you would print just a single int. Loop through the array and `cout` every element.

Comment: `cout<<A[j];` is not how you print a char array. You need loop. A for loop would do ..

Comment: @Pontifex  can you please attach the link to your code and how should I do that, shall I re-start the array in another for or try nesting the for?

Comment: @drescherjm since it's inside the first loop i thought the loop will iterate the value of "j".

Comment: It's not in the first loop. I fixed the formatting and added the updated code to your question.

Comment: @drescherjm in the code i posted above it was inside the for loop why don't you show your code and fix this issue?

Comment: for(int var = 0; var < length; var++) { cout << A[var]; }

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/149651/discussion-between-saubhagya-srivastava-and-drescherjm).

Comment: @Pontifex still wrong output ...http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/f26018db391654c8

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace:

```
while(i>0 && A[i]>key)
```

by:

```
while (i >= 0 && A[i] > key)//notice the equality sign!
```

It was just checking till the 1st index while the zeroth index was not touched

And you might want to print the contents of the array like this:

```
for(int i=0;i<6;i++)
    cout << A[i]<<" ";
```

Answer (score 2):

For starters this loop

```
 for (j = 2; j < length; j++) {
      ^^^^^
```

has an incorrect initial setting. It will not sort an array that has only two elements or the second element will be never swapped with the first element if the second element is less than the first element.

It would be correctly to write the statement like

```
 for (j = 1; j < length; j++) {
      ^^^^^
```

The inner loop

```
while (i > 0 && A[i] > key) {
```

does not touch the element `A[0]` due to the condition `i > 0`, Thus the subcondition `A[0] > key` will be never checked.

It is better instead of swapping each pair of elements that satisfy the condition just to copy elements and then to write the "added" element in the required position.

The program can look the following way.

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    int a[] = { 31, 41, 59, 26, 41, 58 };
    const size_t N = sizeof(a) / sizeof(*a);

    for (int x : a) std::cout << x << ' ';
    std::cout << std::endl;

    for (size_t i = 1; i < N; i++)
    {
        int value = a[i];
        size_t j = i;

        for (; j != 0 && value < a[j - 1]; --j)
        {
            a[j] = a[j - 1];
        }

        if (j != i) a[j] = value;
    }

    for (int x : a) std::cout << x << ' ';
    std::cout << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

The program output is

```
31 41 59 26 41 58
26 31 41 41 58 59
```